# Using the indexer of HttpResponse.Cookies will add a cookie to the response and to the request. What is the idea behind this?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I only realized this, when my website suddenly returned empty cookies, after I had replaced some legacy code with the usage of HttpContext.Response.Cookies via indexer. For example:

`HttpCookie objCookie = HttpContext.Response.Cookies["TrackingId"];`
This line will add a cookie named "TrackingId" to the response and to the request, if it does not exists yet.

To me it is sort of surprising as I would have never expected such drastic behavior from a simple get-call on the indexer; especially, when the collection has a dedicated "Add"-method. Also, the indexer has a setter.

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> After you add a cookie by using the HttpResponse.Cookies collection, the cookie is immediately available in the HttpRequest.Cookies collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client.

I already found a way to avoid this problem.
My question is:

Why would you make the class behave this way?

Comment: How else are you going to add cookies?

Comment: By using the method "Add". ` HttpContext.Response.Add(new HttpCookie("TrackingId"));`